# Вопросы по педпрактике

Tags: лексика, семантика

У меня в этом году появилась педагогическая практика. У меня в связи с ней есть некоторые вопросы по семантике:

1. Преподаватель, которого мне назначили в помощь, для консультаций — это руководитель, куратор?
2. Педагогическая практика — это предмет, дисциплина, или какой иной гипероним для определения можно подобрать?

Answer (score 1):

1. Чуть точнее, я думаю, подойдёт термин **наставник**. *Руководитель* и *куратор* тоже, но эти термины обременены также другими значениями/коннотациями.
2. Практика практике рознь. В каких-то случаях педагогическая практика — одна из форм образовательного процесса (наряду с лекциями, семинарами, лабораторными работами и т.п.). В более сложном варианте (который Вас и интересует, как я понимаю) гиперонимом для "педагогической практики" является **стажировка** — вид дополнительного профессионального образования. Подробнее расшифровку этого термина можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ppt.ru/docs/pismo/goskomvuz/n-18-34-44in-18-10-58351).

Comment: Дисциплина и предмет — некорректно?

Comment: Я бы сказал, что некорректно.